# firebase transaction and if-then-else behaviour

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have some changes in my requirements:

Not only Create/Request/Cancel an entire Offer but do some actions on Offer's details:

Here is an offer in the activeOffers list:

```
activeOffers
    -LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p
        details
            direction: "city"
            seatsCount: 2
            timeToGo: 5
        uid: "-ABSIFJ0vCnt9p8387a"    ---- offering user
```

A user should be able to 'ask for seats' and if it's successful the Offer record should look like this:

```
activeOffers
    -LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p
        details
            direction: "city"
            seatsCount: 1   ----- reduced count
            timeToGo: 5
        uid: "-ABSIFJ0vCnt9p8387a"
    deals
        -GHFFJ0vCnt9p8345b   -----   the userId of asking user
            seatsCount: 1
            status: "asked"
```

But I have 3 problems after executing the source shown below:

(as shown above offer has 2 seats and a user asks for 1 seat)

1. After execution in my log I have BOTH "Reducing seats count by 1" and "Not enought seats"... i.e: the 'then' and 'else' part of 'if-then-else' :o
2. function result is [] - i.e. no deal created.
3. I'm not sure how to do the TODO: part - to add child (the new deal object) under dealsRef using asking userId as KEY because I think I don't need an autogenerated key here.

input data has the following structure:

```
data
    "uid": "-GHFFJ0vCnt9p8345b",    ----- the userId of asking user
    "id": "-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p",    ----- the id of offer
    "details":
        "seatsCount": 1
```

And here is my code:

```
dealSeats = function(data) {

const TAG = '[dealSeats]: ';

var details = data.details;
var info = data.info;

var entryRef = db.ref('activeOffers/' + data.id);
var entryDetailsRef = entryRef.child('details');
var seatsCountRef = entryDetailsRef.child('seatsCount');

var success = false;
return seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    var value = current;
    if (value >= details.seatsCount) {
        success = true;
        value = value - details.seatsCount;
        console.log(TAG + 'Reducing seats count by ' + details.seatsCount);
    } else {
        console.log(TAG + 'Not enought seats');
    }
    return value;
})
.then(()=>{
    var deal = [];
    if (success) {
        console.log(TAG + 'Succes');
        deal.seatsCount = details.seatsCount;
        deal.status = 'asked';
    // TODO: here should add the new deal to dealsRef
        return deal;
    } else {
        console.log(TAG + 'Failure');
        return deal;
    }
})
}
```

And as you can see - I'm not sure what is the right way to check if transaction is succeeded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference documentation for `DatabaseReference.transaction` says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction):

> ...  until your write succeeds without conflict or **you abort the transaction by not returning a value from your update function**.

So the way to abort the transaction is by not returning any value from your update function. That means the entire first block can be simplified to:

```
seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    if (current >= details.seatsCount) {
        return value - details.seatsCount;
    }
})
```

Now it either returns the new value, or it returns nothing. The latter will then make Firebase abort the transaction.

To detect the final output of a transaction, I find it easiest to work with a completion callback (instead of a Promise), since it gives you all parameters in one call:

```
seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    if (current >= details.seatsCount) {
        return value - details.seatsCount;
    }
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
  } else if (!committed) {
    console.log('We aborted the transaction, because there are not enough seats.');
  } else {
    console.log('Seat count updated');
  }
})
```

The most common cause for that first error condition will be that the transaction had to be retried too frequently, meaning that too many users are trying to claim seats at the same time. A typical solution here would be to back off, i.e. have the client retry later.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. 

1. What about the warning during the deploy about not returning a value by the update function?


'warning  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return'


2. What about adding a child to dealsRef with existing key (asking user uid) ?

Comment: And another thing - even if decreasing of seatsCounts is successful the dealSeats() returns null.

I'm not sure how to 'force' the transaction callback to return the deal variable as dealSeats() result.

Maybe it's not a good idea to try to execute a transaction over seatsCount and 'build' a result variable for the dealSeats() in the same code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. When you run a transaction on `/activeOffers/-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p/seatsCount`, **that** is the only node you can update. If you want to update nodes outside of that, you should run your transaction at a higher-level node. E.g. `/activeOffers/-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p`.

Comment: Aha, so if I understand correctly I cannot add **deal** node to **-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p** inside this transaction callback. I should run a transaction on **-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p** itself and inside this transaction I manipulate seatsCount and add **deal** subnode, right ?

Comment: And what about the warning in case the transaction update function does not return a value (i.e. transaction is aborted)

Comment: "I should run a transaction on -LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p itself" Correct. You should run your transaction on the lowest level in the tree that covers all data it needs to read or write.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark your answer as accepted although I'm still getting this 'warning Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function consistent-return' during the deploy via VSCode terminal.