# firebase transcational decrease value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have the following problems:

Transaction update function problem:

Try to **decrease** the current value stored at a realtime database path.
I try to handle the first time transaction is called when the current value is null in a similar way I've seen in many answers about **increase**.
e.g. increase read count etc.

In all examples is shown in a similar way:

```
    return (current || 0) + 1;
```

But in my case I need to **decrease** some value only if current value is bigger than a parameter.
Multiple users may try decrease same value so I need to do this in a transaction.
Here is my code:

```
    seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
        if ((current || 0) >= 1) {
            return (current || 0) - 1;
        } 
    })
```

But decreasing never succeeds. So this is my main problem in point 1.

My other problem in point 1 is: According the doc if I don't return anything the transaction is aborted.

I try this way too:

```
    ...
    else {
        return; // abort the transaction
    }
```

But in both cases I got warning on deploying. Any hint about it ?

**==== I've cut off the other part because as  Frank van Puffelen said it was a separate question ===**

So now it's a simple question without external dependencies.

I just want to know what is the correct way to do decrease in transaction.

because ALL examples and tutorials are about increase and the update function is simply

```
    return (current || 0) + 1;
```

but when I try to do

```
    if ((current || 0) >= 1) {
        return (current || 0) - 1;
    }
```

the transaction never succeeds.

Comment: You have two separate questions in this post. Please limit each post to a single question, and do your best best to [create a minimal complete verifiable reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in each post. That second snippet for example looks quite involved, and we still don't see what `data` is and where it comes from. Try to create a single piece of code that has no external dependencies, and include the JSON that it manipulates (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: sorry, my fault. I've edited the post in order to not include data and external dependencies.  I've added the json in db it tries to manipulate.

Comment: What do you expect `return new Error('Failure', error);` to do? At that point the transaction has already completed, so there's nothing you can do to atomically change the database anymore.

Comment: Ok, I've cut off the second question.
I need advice about the basic one - decrease in transaction. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your advices, Frank van Puffelen,

After some more experiments I have a code that works for me:

(And handles the null case)

```
return seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    if (current) {
        if (current >= 1) {
            return current - 1;
        }
    }
    return current;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This code won't work:

```
seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    if ((current || 0) >= 1) {
        return (current || 0) - 1;
    } 
})
```

Remember what I showed in your [first question on this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023800/firebase-transaction-and-if-then-else-behaviour):

> ... until your write succeeds without conflict or **you abort the transaction by not returning a value** from your update function.

Now look at your code, knowing that the first time it runs Firebase likely passes `null` in for the current value:

```
if ((current || 0) >= 1) {
    return (current || 0) - 1;
}
```

If `current` is `null`, this turns into:

```
if ((null || 0) >= 1) {
    return (null || 0) - 1;
}
```

Which turns into:

```
if (0 >= 1) {
    return 0 - 1;
}
```

And since `0 >= 1` if `false`, you are not returning a value, and thus abort the transaction.

You'll need to handle this initial `null`. Even when your use-case says it is impossible that the value will even not exist, your code will need to handle it anyway, since the Firebase SDK may pass you `null` as part of its operation.

Since the `null` can't really exist in your database, it doesn't really matter **what** you return in that case. All that matters is that you return *something* to make sure the transaction isn't aborted. For example, this would work:

```
seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    if ((current || 0) >= 1) {
        return (current || 0) - 1;
    } 
    return "This will never be stored";
})
```

But since this value will never be stored, you might as well simply return the `-1` that the simplest code results in:

```
seatsCountRef.transaction((current)=>{
    return (current || 0) - 1;
})
```

If you are concerned about this invalid value ever being stored, you could catch this in [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and reject it:

```
"seatsCount": {
  ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >== 0"
}
```

That actually is a pretty good practice in general: once your data model stabilizes, use validation rules to enforce it. It won't make a difference here though, since you already say that `seatsCount` must exist. But just in case it doesn't, this security rule will catch the output of the transaction.